# Why $R(D)$ is not measured in LHCb and only $R(D^*)$ is measured?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, large-hadron-collider, mesons

Measurement of $R(D)$ and $R(D^*)$ are important probe of lepton universality violation. They are defined as the ratios of branching fractions:
$$R(D^{(*)}) = \frac{\mathcal{B}(B\rightarrow D^{(*)}\tau \nu)}{\mathcal{B}(B\rightarrow D^{(*)}\mu \nu)}$$
I could not find any reference discussing about why it is not possible to measure the ratio $R(D)$ in LHCb. On the other hand $R(D^*)$ is measured in LHCb in 2017 https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.10651.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decay $D^* \to D \pi$ produces a 'slow pion', as the $D^*$ has barely enough mass for this to be possible. This slow pion gives an effective handle enabling one to identify a clean $D^*$ signal. This is needed because  the tau decay mode is a very difficult channel to identify, as there are two unseen neutrinos in the final state. Measuring $R(D)$ is not kinematically impossible, just very difficult without the helpful slow pion tag.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What I undrstood is that, in LHCb $B\rightarrow D^* \tau \nu$ can be identified due to the 'slow pion' coming from $D^*\rightarrow D \pi$. In the case of $B\rightarrow D \tau \nu$, there is no such 'slow pion' signal. The $\tau\rightarrow \mu \nu \nu$ process results in three $\nu$ in the final state. These three $\nu$ can be used to identify $B\rightarrow D\tau \nu$, but it is difficult to do in LHCb. One doubt, in Belle, the $R(D)$ can be measured, is it because there is $B-\bar B$ production that helps with identification of   $B\rightarrow D\tau \nu$?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple:

The mass of [the tau lepton](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/tables/rpp2019-sum-leptons.pdf) is    1776.86 ± 0.12 MeV.

The mass of [the D resonance](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/tables/rpp2018-tab-mesons-charm.pdf) is    1869.65 ± 0.05 MeV

The mass of the first $D^*$      is    2006.85 ± 0.05 MeV

There is not enough energy in the center of mass  for the D to decay into a $τ$ lepton , the  $τ$ decay product to have enough energy for identification in the aparatus. In the center of mass the energy will be split with the neutrino from momentum conservation . Using the $D^*$ allows enough energy  for the decay products of a charged pion, a neutral pion (2 gammas),to be detected in the apparatus.

If you look at the [univesality tests](https://lhcbproject.web.cern.ch/lhcbproject/Publications/LHCbProjectPublic/Summary_all.html) in the LHB publications you will not find one for the $D^*$  . They use the much heavier B resonances.

Reading [your link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.10651) , it seems that they chose the particular reaction because it allowed the possibility of isolating the desired ratio from the background. It could be the main reason for the choice,  The higher available center of  mass energy allowing for better identification of the $D^*$ decay products .

Comment: Mass of D meson is ~1869.65 GeV. Sorry, I did not get why there is not enough energy in the c.o.m for D to decay into $\tau$ lepton. Why do we need D to decay into $\tau$ lepton anyway?

Comment: A minor point: LHCb uses $B^0 \to D^{*-}(\to D^0 \pi^-) \tau^+ \nu_\tau$, so no need to reconstruct $\pi^0 \to \gamma \gamma$, which LHCb is bad at doing even in at the best of times, let alone a slow pion from a $D^{*0}$.

Answer (score 0):

In measuring $R(D)$ properly, we also have to consider the strong feed-down from $B \to D^{*}\tau \nu$, due to the reasons alluded to in RogerJBarlow's answer.

This makes the analysis effectively a simultaneous measurement of both $R(D)$ and $R(D^*)$. This adds an extra layer of complexity (e.g. need to get the correct covariances and check consistency with the standalone $R(D^*)$ measurement) therefore it takes longer. We do have a blinded measurement going through the review process at the moment, for what it's worth.

Comment: As a small update, here is the paper: https://lhcbproject.web.cern.ch/Publications/LHCbProjectPublic/LHCb-PAPER-2022-039.html